# Change field type for custom entity (from integer to decimal) with existing data

Tags: 8, entities

Yes I have seen previous answers about that, but I'm looking for an new answer :

- That does not use SQL request
- That does not use deprecated function like `db_change_field()`
- maybe that uses the new API (see https://www.drupal.org/node/3029997)

I'm not familiar enough with the Drupal 8 storage system so I also look for insight.

I have looked into a lot of documentation, including :

- https://www.drupal.org/node/3034742 (example included for a schema change, for a revisionable field)
- https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/update-api/updating-entities-and-fields-in-drupal-8#updating-a-base-field-type (which feels to be the best answer yet)

What get my attention is this : "Starting with Drupal 8.7.0, the Entity system provides a new Update API for converting the schema of a content entity type from (non-)revisionable/(non-)translatable to revisionable/translatable, **which also works when there is pre-existing data for the entity type whose schema is being changed**.."

Which indicated some built-in way to change a field type with existing data without having to write lots of code.

So I tried this to change a field type of my custom entity which already have data (~ 10000 rows).

```
function mymodule_post_update_0011_field_conversion(array $sandbox) {
    $definition_update_manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
    $last_installed_schema_repository = \Drupal::service('entity.last_installed_schema.repository');

    $entity_type = $definition_update_manager->getEntityType('my_entity_id');
    $field_storage_definitions = $last_installed_schema_repository->getLastInstalledFieldStorageDefinitions('my_entity_id');

    // Update field already existing in $field_storage_definitions
   // I also tried to create a new field, with the same outcome.
    $field_storage_definitions['order_vat'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('decimal')
      ->setLabel(t('Order VAT Rate'))
      ->setDescription(t('Order VAT Rate.'))
      ->setSettings(['precision' => 5, 'scale' => 2]);

    \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager()
      ->updateFieldableEntityType($entity_type, $field_storage_definitions,$sandbox);
  }
```

Which ends with a `Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException : Unsupported entity type`

I tried to use this same function to add a new field in the entity, with the same error as outcome.

Is there something wrong with my attempt, and is the only way to manage this is to manually, inside a `post_update_hook`, to create a new field with the appropriate type, copy all values from the old one to the new one, empty the old one, and delete the old field ?

That seems a lot for a simple operation, which, in my case, I could do with a quite simple SQL statement.

Last precision, this is a custom entity, created from code only (`ContentEntityBase`), without any revision (for now), which content is only manipulated programmatically.